# Have Javascript (not JQuery) move table row (TR) up or down, not just the Cell (TD)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have Javascript (not JQuery) move table row (TR) up or down, not just the block of TD Cells.

Add 2 Rows, then you notice that it just moves the cell down or up when you click the up or down button, but not the entire rows color.  The information looks like it all gets moved.

I am using javascript only, so JQuery wont work.

Codepen of working code
https://codepen.io/soljohnston777/pen/zYBrMxL

```js
var activeRow = 0;

function setActiveRow(el) {
  var rows = document.getElementById('movingTable').rows;
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i] == el) activeRow = i;
  }
}

function moveActiveRow(move) {
  var rows = document.getElementById('movingTable').rows;
  var oldRow = rows[activeRow].innerHTML;
  var newRow = rows[activeRow + move].innerHTML;
  rows[activeRow].innerHTML = newRow;
  rows[activeRow + move].innerHTML = oldRow;
  setActiveRow(rows[activeRow + move]);
}

function moveRow(cell, move) {
  // alert("Row index is: " + cell.name);
  setActiveRow(cell.parentNode);
  moveActiveRow(move);
}

function doSubmit() {
  var rows = document.getElementById('movingTable').rows;
  var ret = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    ret[ret.length] = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML;
  }
  return ret.join('|');
}

function AddSection() {

  var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");

  AddRow(txtName.value, "1");
  txtName.value = "";
};

function AddLesson() {

  var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");

  AddRow(txtName.value, "2");
  txtName.value = "";
};

function AddRow(name, section) {
  var table = document.getElementById("movingTable");
  // 1 section , 2 lesson
  if (section == "1") {
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var input1 = document.createElement('input');
    input1.type = "hidden";
    var input2 = document.createElement('input');
    input2.type = "text";
    input2.setAttribute("value", name);
    input2.setAttribute("name", "section[]");
    input2.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #5cffde;");
    var inputhidden1 = document.createElement('input');
    inputhidden1.type = "hidden";
    inputhidden1.setAttribute("name", "section[]");

    var inputhidden2 = document.createElement('input');
    inputhidden2.type = "hidden";

    var input3 = document.createElement('input');
    input3.type = "button";
    input3.value = "Up";
    input3.setAttribute("onclick", "moveRow(this, -1);");

    var input4 = document.createElement('input');
    input4.type = "button";
    input4.value = "Down";
    input4.setAttribute("onclick", "moveRow(this, 1);");

    var input5 = document.createElement('input');
    input5.type = "button";
    input5.value = "Remove";
    input5.setAttribute("onclick", "Remove(this);");

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell1.appendChild(input1);
    cell2.appendChild(input2);
    cell2.appendChild(inputhidden1);
    cell2.appendChild(inputhidden2);
    cell3.appendChild(input3);
    cell4.appendChild(input4);
    cell5.appendChild(input5);
    inputhidden1 = "";
    inputhidden2 = "";
  }
  if (section == "2") {
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var input1 = document.createElement('input');
    input1.type = "hidden";
    var input2 = document.createElement('input');
    input2.type = "text";
    input2.setAttribute("value", name);
    input2.setAttribute("name", "Lesson[]");


    var input3 = document.createElement('input');
    input3.type = "button";
    input3.value = "Up";
    input3.setAttribute("onclick", "moveRow(this, -1);");

    var input4 = document.createElement('input');
    input4.type = "button";
    input4.value = "Down";
    input4.setAttribute("onclick", "moveRow(this, 1);");

    var input5 = document.createElement('input');
    input5.type = "button";
    input5.value = "Remove";
    input5.setAttribute("onclick", "Remove(this);");

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell1.appendChild(input1);
    cell2.appendChild(input2);
    cell3.appendChild(input3);
    cell4.appendChild(input4);
    cell5.appendChild(input5);
  }


  var colors = new Array('#ffffff', '#dddddd', '#aaaaaa', '#888888');

  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    doMultiple(rows[i], i, rows[i].className);
  }

  function doMultiple(row, i, s) {
    if (section == "1" || s == "sections") {
      row.className = "sections";
    } else {
      row.style.backgroundColor = colors[i % colors.length];
    }
  }
}

function Remove(button) {
  //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
  var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
  var name = row.getElementsByTagName("TD")[0].innerHTML;
  if (confirm("Do you want to delete this?")) {

    //Get the reference of the Table.
    var table = document.getElementById("movingTable");
    //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
    table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
  }
};
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  border: solid 1px #e7e7e7;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.sections {
  background-color: #5cffde;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="mTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Section?</td>
      <td>Section/Lesson Name</td>
      <td>Move Up</td>
      <td>Move Down</td>
      <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="movingTable">
</table>
<table width="100" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="">
  <tfoot>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="AddSection()" value="Add Section" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="AddLesson()" value="Add Lesson" /></td>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: never, ever, ever, use `.innerHTML` for moving DOM elements.   Use [`Node#insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to move a child from one place in the DOM to another.

Comment: show me an example in this context please. :)

Comment: Why have you got three separate `<table>` elements? What is it you're trying to do, insert `<tr>` elements (along with `<td>` children) and be able to just move those `<tr>` elements up and/or down?

Comment: Well I used 3 tables because the <thead> gets messed with and so did the <tfoot> footer with this code.  This created a consistent box (the middle table) to put the dynamic table into and have it be able to be moved around. I would like to just move the <tr> elements up and down instead of the <td> elements.